# Make Windows logo key + number open buttons that belong to the same program

Tags: windows-10, taskbar

I've disabled taskbar button grouping in Windows. But I noticed that Windows still doesn't treat opened instances of a program as independent.

Below, when I press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>, it takes me to Onenote
instead of the second Chrome window. I've searched in Windows taskbar settings and haven't found such an option.

[image]

Comment: The Winkey + number shortcuts were introduced at the same time as taskbar button grouping in Windows 7. I think it works as intended but maybe Microsoft just never thought about using these shortcuts in combination with taskbar button grouping disabled. 
There is no builtin way in Windows to change what these shortcuts do. You could however do one of the following things:
You can simply press the same number key again to to the next window or you could look for a third party solution to change what these shortcuts do (like AutoHotkey)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://rammichael.com/7-taskbar-tweaker
select don't group,   2nd row